# How to do transform CALayer without changing it's shape

Tags: ios, calayer

I've a rectangle shaped `CALayer`, which I've scaled as below:

```
CATransform3D currentTransform = layer.transform;
CATransform3D newTransform = CATransform3DScale(currentTransform, xscale, yscale, 1.0);
[layer setTransform:newTransform];
```

After applying `CATransform3DScale`, transformed `CALayer` is also a rectangle.

But when I apply `CATransform3DRotate`, transformed `CALayer` becomes a rhombus.

```
CATransform3D currentTransform = layer.transform;
CATransform3D newTransform = CATransform3DRotate(currentTransform, rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
[layer setTransform:newTransform];
```

How can I get the rectangle shape after applying rotate transform?

I didn't change anchor point of the layer. Sometimes I need to change the position of the layer.